# How to combine two outputs of KernelDensity from sklearn (Python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kernel-density

I want to multiply two Kernel Density Estimates to get a composite likelihood ... The multiplication operator doesn't exist for sklearn.

I have KDR for data from 3 independent sources and I want multiply KDE from each sources. The below code is from https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_species_kde.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-neighbors-plot-species-kde-py and should run easily.

Although I made some small modification to get get two KDEs and then multiply them which fails.

Someone can help. Below code should run without error except the multiplication part.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_species_distributions
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

# if basemap is available, we'll use it.
# otherwise, we'll improvise later...
try:
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
    basemap = True
except ImportError:
    basemap = False

def construct_grids(batch):
    """Construct the map grid from the batch object

    Parameters
    ----------
    batch : Batch object
        The object returned by :func:`fetch_species_distributions`

    Returns
    -------
    (xgrid, ygrid) : 1-D arrays
        The grid corresponding to the values in batch.coverages
    """
    # x,y coordinates for corner cells
    xmin = batch.x_left_lower_corner + batch.grid_size
    xmax = xmin + (batch.Nx * batch.grid_size)
    ymin = batch.y_left_lower_corner + batch.grid_size
    ymax = ymin + (batch.Ny * batch.grid_size)

    # x coordinates of the grid cells
    xgrid = np.arange(xmin, xmax, batch.grid_size)
    # y coordinates of the grid cells
    ygrid = np.arange(ymin, ymax, batch.grid_size)

    return (xgrid, ygrid)

# Get matrices/arrays of species IDs and locations
data = fetch_species_distributions()
species_names = ['Bradypus Variegatus', 'Microryzomys Minutus']

Xtrain = np.vstack([data['train']['dd lat'], data['train']['dd long']]).T
ytrain = np.array([d.decode('ascii').startswith('micro')
                  for d in data['train']['species']], dtype='int')
Xtrain *= np.pi / 180.  # Convert lat/long to radians

# Set up the data grid for the contour plot
xgrid, ygrid = construct_grids(data)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xgrid[::5], ygrid[::5][::-1])
land_reference = data.coverages[6][::5, ::5]
land_mask = (land_reference > -9999).ravel()

xy = np.vstack([Y.ravel(), X.ravel()]).T
xy = xy[land_mask]
xy *= np.pi / 180.

# Plot map of South America with distributions of each species
fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=0.95, wspace=0.05)

kde0 = KernelDensity(bandwidth=0.04, metric='haversine',
                    kernel='gaussian', algorithm='ball_tree')
kde0.fit(Xtrain[ytrain == 0])

kde1 = KernelDensity(bandwidth=0.04, metric='haversine',
                    kernel='gaussian', algorithm='ball_tree')
kde1.fit(Xtrain[ytrain == 1])

kde01=kde0*kde1

plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)

# evaluate only on the land: -9999 indicates ocean
Z = np.full(land_mask.shape[0], -9999, dtype='int')
Z[land_mask] = np.exp(kde01.score_samples(xy))
Z = Z.reshape(X.shape)

# plot contours of the density
levels = np.linspace(0, Z.max(), 25)
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=levels, cmap=plt.cm.Reds)

plt.show()
```